# How to pass data from Grandchild to Parent component in React Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, parent-child, react-functional-component

I have a function in GrandChild.tsx

GrandChild.tsx

```
function grandChild(){  
   function a(){ someVariables } 
}
```

Parent.tsx

```
function Parent(){
  console.log(someVariables) 
}
```

How can I pass data from GrandChild to Parent component ?

I've tried this method:

Parent.tsx

```
function Parent(){ 

const (msg, setMsg) = useState('') function getData(){ <Child someVar = {msg}/> }
```

Child.tsx

```
interface ChildProps {
 someVar: any;
}

function Child(props: ChildProps){
const (mediator, setMediator) = useState('') 

function mediateData(){ <Child someVariables = {msg}/> } }
```

GrandChild.tsx

```
interface GrandChildProps {
 someVariables: any;
}

function GrandChild(props: GrandChildProps){
const (data, sendData) = useState('') 
function a(){ <GrandChild someVariables = {data}/> }
```

Comment: I made a little demo on codesandbox, hope this can help: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-pine-1z9ms

Comment: I wanted to pass data (other way around) from GrandChildren.tsx to Parent.tsx

Comment: sorry i had missread it, fixed and posted an answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the codesandbox from my comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-pine-1z9ms

The the idea here is to pass down the "setMsg" function and call it from the Grandchild

Comment: Yes. I can confirm. This is the classical way.